# Python program to send reminder email 2 weeks before given dates within a dictionary

Tags: python, email, time, reminders

I have a list called "results" that contains 50 dictionaries of patients and their info including their appointment date. I'm trying to create a reminder system that sends an email 2 weeks and 2 days before a patient's appointment. I'm having trouble creating the program that compares today's date to the appointment date and pulls out the appointments that are 2 weeks from today's date and 2 days.

this is the script i have so far but can't figure out how to include the 2 weeks and 2 days condition

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
current_date= (now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
current_time= (now.strftime("%I:%M %p"))
for i in results:
    if i['Appointment Date'] >= current_date:
        print("Upcoming Appointment")
    else:
        print("Passed Appointment")
```

Comment: Why are you creating strings from `datetime` objects? Given that you have `%m/%d/%Y` as a date format, the comparison isn't doing what you think it is doing. What's wrong with parsing the date value from `i` into a `datetime` and use that to compare against the current date. As for the delta: have a look at [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

Comment: how would you parse the data value from i into datetime?

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert `i['Appointment Date']` to `datetime` object and then check it with today's date.

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in results:
    # convert to datetime, assuming the string format is "YYYY/MM/DD"
    target_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(i['Appointment Date'],"%Y/%m/%d")
    diff = target_date - now
    if diff.days==14 or diff.days==2: # check for 2 days or 14 days
        print("Upcoming Appointment")
    else:
        print("Passed Appointment")
```

Comment: thank you! but i got this error?: "AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'"

Comment: Updated the code, it should be datetime.datetime.strptime

Comment: the string format is actually in "MM/DD/YYYY" so i adjusted that in the code you gave to "%m/%d/%Y", but after run it I get: " ValueError: time data 'Appointment Date' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' "?

Comment: Ah, 'Appointment Date' came up. i think my issue is with my dictionary. I have a txt file filled with patient info and I had to convert that txt file into a dictionary. I must have coded it wrong, which is why I can't pull out the appoint date values?

Comment: Yes, it seems like it. Add that piece of code as a part of the question, if you need help with that.

Comment: I do have one more thing, I'm not sure if this matters, but if i put in the terminal:----  for  i in results:
    print(i['Appointment Date']) ----then all the appointment date get printed (i.e., Appointment Date
01/09/2018
01/23/2018
02/08/2018
02/09/2018
02/19/2018
02/23/2018
03/02/2018
03/23/2018 and so forth with the total 50 dates

Comment: Ahh, you need to skip the first index, as it seems to contain your headers, do try "for i in results[1:]:" instead of "for i in results:"

Comment: i think it works! how would I continue the code you gave to get python to print all the dates 2 weeks from now?

Comment: Agh, I'm still running into some problems. I really appreciate your help though, it's helped tremendously!

Comment: Glad to help, please mark this answer as the correct one if it solved what you originally asked

Comment: once i figure it out, i will! I'm still waiting for any responses that help with the ending code that prints out the dates in the list that meet the 2 weeks/2 days criteria

Comment: Updated the printing part